# OnMouseButtonDown raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a mobile game project on Unity. I have a problem while trying to get collided item and working mechanic of Ray. Here is the code:

```
void Update () {

int boxNumber = -1;

//Change with touch inputs
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
    mouseDownX = Input.mousePosition.x;
    mouseDownY = Input.mousePosition.y;
    xMove = true;
    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit ();
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 100)) {
        boxNumber = int.Parse (hit.collider.gameObject.name);
    }
}
if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){
    mouseUpX = Input.mousePosition.x;
    mouseUpY = Input.mousePosition.y;
    yMove = true;
}
if(yMove == true && boxNumber != -1){
    boxDecider (boxNumber,getDirection());
    Debug.Log (getDirection());
        yMove = false;
        xMove = false;
    }
}
```

`getDirection()` `boxDecider()` methods are created by me and are working well. When first `if` statement is activated(when mouse button down) it finds the collided object correctly but it calls the `boxDecider()` method WITHOUT releasing the mouse button but it should call the method after releasing the mouse button.

Comment: you must be calling the `boxDecider()` method somwhere else in your code. Look for it by right clicking in visual studio and then clicking 'Find All Refrences'. This will show you everywhere that it is being called. Make sure it is just where you want it.

Comment: is yMove public or private? Maybe it's public and you've changed it's default value to true in the editor. (Even if you declare it as public yMove=false, but set it true in the Editor, the value true will be it's default). To avoid any mistakes, make sure you have yMove=false in your Start() function.